# Error in mutate_at when trying to create new variables using tidyselect function when knitting R markdown

Tags: r, knitr, dplyr, tidyselect

It's highly likely that I'm missing something really simple, but I cannot work out why this error is persisting in my mutate_at function.

```
library(tidyverse)
test = data.frame(diff_1 = sample(0:10, size=20, replace=TRUE),
                  diff_2 = sample(0:10, size=20, replace=TRUE),
                  diff_3 = sample(0:10, size=20, replace=TRUE))
test2 = test %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(contains("diff_")), .funs = list(cat = ~as.factor(ntile(., 5)))) # create quintiles of variables
```

I am trying to produce new columns with suffixes ("_cat") added at the end of variable names using mutate_at, but get the following error when trying to select variables that contain "diff_", which I cannot work out why...:'(

```
Error: `.vars` must be a character/numeric vector or a `vars()` object, not a `data.frame` object
```

**EDIT:**

When I run the R markdown in sections, the test code works after I have restarted R. But the error message persists whenever I try to knit the whole markdown workbook. This means that I can't just restart RStudio to fix this error.

```
Quitting from lines 1008-1040 (analysis-complete-case-FIoriginal.Rmd) 
Error: `.vars` must be a character/numeric vector or a `vars()` object, not a `data.frame` object
```

I've downloaded the most recent versions of R and RStudio but still no luck :(. I wonder if anyone could shed light on why this error message might be occurring? Is it problem with the tidyselect function?

Thank you!

**EDIT2:**

For reference, the full code for this section is:

```
transposed_cont = mydata_cont %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=all_of(myvarscont), names_to = "myvars", values_to = "value") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = source, values_from = value) %>% 
  mutate(diff_w2w1 = wave2-wave1,
         diff_w3w1 = wave3-wave1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(., id_cols=id, names_from=myvars, values_from=c("wave1", "wave2", "wave3", "diff_w2w1", "diff_w3w1")) %>% # allows you to spread multiple values
  dplyr::select(id, wave1_fi.score, wave2_fi.score, wave1_fp.count, wave2_fp.count, starts_with("diff")) %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(contains("diff_"), .funs = list(cat = ~as.factor(ntile(., 5)))) ## THIS IS WHERE THE CODE FAILS
```

The problem seems to be in the last line of my code `vars(contains("diff_")` when I knit the Rmarkdown. Currently, I have a very crude workaround where I've listed the variables instead as such:

```
tempvars = c(Cs(diff_w2w1_chronic_count, diff_w2w1_cvd_count, diff_w2w1_overnight_num, diff_w2w1_falls_count, diff_w2w1_mmse_errors,  
diff_w2w1_MHcesd,  diff_w2w1_COGimmediaterecall1, diff_w2w1_COGimmediaterecall2, diff_w2w1_COGdelayedrecall, diff_w2w1_bmi,
diff_w3w1_chronic_count, diff_w3w1_cvd_count, diff_w3w1_overnight_num, diff_w3w1_falls_count, diff_w3w1_FRtscore, 
diff_w3w1_mmse_errors, diff_w3w1_moca_errors, diff_w3w1_MHcesd, diff_w3w1_COGimmediaterecall1, diff_w3w1_COGimmediaterecall2, 
diff_w3w1_COGdelayedrecall, diff_w3w1_COGtrail1time, diff_w3w1_COGtrail2time, diff_w3w1_COGtraildeltatime, diff_w3w1_CRTmeancog, 
diff_w3w1_CRTmeanmot, diff_w3w1_CRTmeantot, diff_w3w1_visualAcuityLeft, diff_w3w1_visualAcuityRight, diff_w3w1_bmi, diff_w3w1_FRwhr))

transposed_cont = mydata_cont %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=all_of(myvarscont), names_to = "myvars", values_to = "value") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = source, values_from = value) %>% 
  mutate(diff_w2w1 = wave2-wave1,
         diff_w3w1 = wave3-wave1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(., id_cols=id, names_from=myvars, values_from=c("wave1", "wave2", "wave3", "diff_w2w1", "diff_w3w1")) %>% # allows you to spread multiple values
  dplyr::select(id, wave1_fi.score, wave2_fi.score, wave1_fp.count, wave2_fp.count, starts_with("diff")) %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = tempvars, .funs = list(cat = ~as.factor(ntile(., 5)))) # create quintiles of variables
```

I was able to knit the output with this crude workaround, but it would be very handy to know why my first attempt failed for future reference.

Comment: There are some other lines of code in your Rmd file. Can you paste them? Specially lines 1008-1040.

Comment: Hi Ronak, thank you for your comment. The code clearly works when I am running the markdown file but not when I'm knitting so I am baffled.

Comment: I did not include the rest of the code as the problem clearly seems to be the last line of code, but I've added more information and my current workaround for your reference.

Comment: Do you mean the first block of EDIT2 gives an error whereas the second block which is workaround works as expected?

Comment: Yes that's correct